# for what x, is $\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot c\cos^{-1}(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers

While solving a question, I met the next problem, for what x, is:
$$ \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \cos^{-1}(x)  \in \mathbb{Q} $$

I found in this [paper](http://www.unirioja.es/cu/jvarona/downloads/arccos.pdf) that for $ 0 \leq r \leq 1, r \in \mathbb{Q} $,

$$ \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \cos^{-1}(\sqrt{r})  \in \mathbb{Q} \iff r = 0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}, 1$$

(the same holds for $\sin^{-1} $)

I would like to know if there is more known about the matter.

(for example what about $\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot\cos^{-1} \sqrt[3]{r}$)

The paper was written by Juan L. Varona

Comment: I think the roots make all the differences.  cos^-1(x) = a$\pi$pi, a rational would only mean x = cos(a$\pi$) which has many trivial solutions.

Comment: ... whereas $\sqrt(r) = cos(a$\pi$) is not in the *least* bit trivial!